# Why must this code line be in synchronized() in spring core?

Tags: java, spring

```
@Override
protected final void refreshBeanFactory() throws BeansException {
    if (hasBeanFactory()) {
        destroyBeans();
        closeBeanFactory();
    }
    try {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = createBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.setSerializationId(getId());
        customizeBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        loadBeanDefinitions(beanFactory);
        synchronized (this.beanFactoryMonitor) {
            this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ApplicationContextException("I/O error parsing bean definition source for " + getDisplayName(), ex);
    }
}
```

The code above is from spring-core (`AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory`). Why must the line

```
this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
```

from the code above be in synchronized()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the Spring context initialization is performed in a single thread there could be other application threads that want to use it. For example the application thread could by calling `ConfigurableApplicationContext#getBeanFactory()` or `ConfigurableApplicationContext#close()` which are both implemented by `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext`. Because of that it's important to synchronize the access to `beanFactory` field which state could be shared between threads.

This particular line [was committed in 2008](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blame/5f4d1a4628513ab34098fa3f92ba03aa20fc4204/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java#L132) and maybe will be revisited as part of [SPR-8767 Parallel bean initialization during startup](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8767).